# Clicked wrong entry during question review

Tags: support, review-queue

I intended to flag the answer as 'not an answer', but clicked on "no action needed".  Is there a way to go back and correct my review?

https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/311708

Comment: I click the back button, open the question, then do the appropriate action(s) - down vote flag etc on it. Don't worry, that's not casting it needs 3 reviewers(?) to leave it open ;-)

Comment: @Tim Thanks.  I did not think of going back to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally click the back button and access the problem post directly (it will be linked), the perform the necessary actions on the question outside the review queue.

Also, don't worry about a mistake - it isn't binding, it needs (3?) more wrong votes to keep it open. (And I've just flagged etc. that one!)

But, as Seth says - do go back!

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: But please go back and correct your misclicks anyway! Sadly, it isn't a good idea to trust others to get it right :(

Comment: @Seth added in :) Very good point :/ I do make accidental clicks, and sometimes I review, then realise I am wrong, esp after seeing the other review's opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back through your list of reviews (either [on your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/283721/charles-green?tab=activity&sort=reviews) or [in review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/history) and find the post. Then you can flag it.